# Sticky nav bar is not clickable until passing parallex section

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is the html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
     <img src="/static/sun1.png" id="sun"> 
     <h2 id="text"><span>Help save our</span><br>Planet</h2>
     <img src="/static/water1.png" id="water">
</section>

<!-- Page content -->
<div class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width:1564px">
```

And here is the code to the nav bar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-wide w3-padding w3-card">
        <a href="/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><b>Taco</b> Project</a>
        <!-- Float links to the right. Hide them on small screens -->
        <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
        <a href="/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a> 
        <a href="/uploadredirect" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Upload</a>
        <a href="/library" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Library</a>
        <a href="/searchredirect" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Search</a>
        <a href="/#capabilities" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Capabilities</a>
        <a href="/#process" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Process</a>
        <a href="/#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">About</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for the parallex section of the website. I believe the problem has something to do with something within the parallex being of higher priority than the navigation bar. A fix I did that stopped the text from going above the nav bar is by changing the z index of the Navbar to 999. I still have the error of not being able to click on the Navbar once I start scrolling as well as it going below the transition between the parallex and the rest of the website :

```
#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10000;
}
#header .nav{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header .logo{
    color: #094b65;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 400px;
}
#header ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#header ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    color: #094b65;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#header ul li a:hover,
#header ul li a.active{
    background: #094b65;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
  background: #01191d;
  min-height: 1500px;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #01191d, transparent);
  z-index: 10000;
}

section:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}

section img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
}
section #text{
    position: relative;
    color: #094b65;
    font-size: 10vw;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0.55em;
    font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
section #text span{
    color: #094b65;
    font-size: 0.20em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10em;
  z-index: 1;
}

#road {
  z-index: 2;
}

p, h3{
  color: white;
}

.sec {
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px;
}
.sec h2{
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sec p{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
}
```

It seems like the issue is that the navbar is going below the parallex, but that doesn't really make sense since I can view it the whole time.

[video demo of the page](https://youtu.be/l2Jm48av2jc)

Comment: You must add your css code.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably `z-index`. Since the banner section has stacked layers it should have z-index set. You need to set a higher z-index for `.w3-top`. May be add `.w3-top{z-index:999}` to the css and check.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. After adding this, the text does now scroll below the Navbar instead of over it, however the navigation bar is still unclickable until the end. I noticed that it also goes below the transition between the parallex and the rest of the website which is something you can see in the YouTube video.

Comment: You have `section:before` and `section:after` elements with `z-index:10000` same as you have for `#header`. Change the `#header` to `z-index:100000`

Comment: thank you! I was so stupid and didnt think to just check the z indexes of my other sections, such an easy fix that took too long.

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass the entire nav bar (all elements supposed to be clickable) in  tags and add 
The function javascript_function() has to contain everything you want to do after the click.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?